# Make Woocommerce custom checkout field not editable

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, checkout

I added a custom field on the woocommerce checkout page that is populated by `URL` but I am struggling to find a way to make this `field` not editable.

I added the following code to  **function.php**:

```
//Add custom field
function custom_woocommerce_checkout_fields( $checkout_fields = array() ) {

    $checkout_fields['order']['imei'] = array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('IMEI'),
        'placeholder'   => __('imei'),
        'default' => $_GET['imei'],            
    );

    return $checkout_fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_checkout_fields' );
```

What should I change in my code to accomplish this ?

Comment: Add `disabled` as an attribute.

Comment: Try `$checkout_fields['order']['_imei']` this way it will be hidden from the admin

Comment: @BoianIvanov I'm not too sure how to add an attribute and can't seem to find a good documentation that explains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this text `<imput>` field with the [**`readonly`**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp) property *(meaning not editable)*.

> You should need to have your 'emei' set in the checkout url like: 
> `http://www.example.com/checkout/?imei=3545454653` to make the field appear with the value as I have this condition: `if( empty($_GET['imei'])) return;`set in the function.

The code:

```
// Display
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'custom_woocommerce_checkout_fields' );
function custom_woocommerce_checkout_fields( $checkout ) {
    // Only display field if the 'emei' is set in the checkout url
    if( empty($_GET['imei'])) return;

    echo '<p class="form-row my-field-class form-row-wide woocommerce-validated" id="imei_field">
        <label for="imei" class="">'.__('IMEI').'</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text " name="imei" id="imei" placeholder="'.__('IMEI').'" value="'.$_GET['imei'].'" readonly>
    </p>';
}

// Save 
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );
function custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['imei'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_imei', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['imei'] ) );
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and work on WooCommerce versions 3+

> **To get the value *(for a defined `$order_id`)*:**
>
> ```
> $imei = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_imei', true );
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Try this code. It work for me. Just need to add custom attribute parameter to the fields array.

```
//Display custom field
function custom_woocommerce_checkout_fields( $checkout_fields = array() ) {

$checkout_fields['order']['imei'] = array(
    'type'          => 'text',
    'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
    'label'         => __('IMEI'),
    'placeholder'   => __('imei'),
    'default' => $_GET['imei'],   
    'custom_attributes' => array( 'disabled' => true)
);

return $checkout_fields;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_checkout_fields' );

// Save custom field
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );
function custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['imei'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_imei', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['imei'] ) );
    }
}
```